# How to Bring Activity(Tasks/Evenets) fields in a data extension in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a requirement where i want to create a new data extension with the Activity information of a contact record.

I had gone to Data Sources-->Set up object and Im able to see Task and Event separately but im not able to find activity.

Can you please let me know how to pull the activity fields to create a new data extension.

Thanks
Abraham

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Activity is not a standard object in Salesforce. Salesforce Events and Tasks are the standard objects that are displayed in Activities related list.

Refer here for the list of [Standard Salesforce Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) and there is clearly no seprate object for activity.

Marketing cloud imports only the objects from Salesforce and so you can view only Tasks and events and not activity.